# Vuejs component template : How to loop through specific array keys using v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for

This is how the template of my component looks like:

```
<tr v-for="row in user.data">

                    <td v-for="(value,key) in row">

                        {{key}}-{{value}}

                    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to exclude some keys from this loop, I know that the best solution is to use the computed function but a don't know how to implement it.

Comment: share sample data ? current output and expected outpu ?

Comment: The [documentation for computed properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) will help you out.  If you're having problems implementing a computed property, please include the code you've tried and explain what errors you're getting or what isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of keys you want to ignore:

```
data: function () {
        return {
            ignore: [
             'key1',
             'key2',
             'key3'
            ]
```

Then add v-if statement that would loop through "ignore" array and skip the output if the key matches:

```
  <td v-for="(value,key) in row"
      v-if="!ignore.includes(row.key)">

                    {{key}}-{{value}}

  </td>
```

Comment: this came in really handy for a specific loop I had.  Great call.
    <template v-for="(value,key) in myObject.array"   v-if="!ignore.includes(key)">

       <li>{{value}}</li>

     </template>
ignore: [
    'page_title',
    'image1',
    'section_title'
    ]